# how can i prove this equation of binomial coefficients?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

i dont know $-a$ in this equation really mean, explain it too please
$$ \left(\begin{array}{c}a+m-1\\ m\end{array}\right) = (-1)^m \left(\begin{array}{c}-a\\ m\end{array}\right) $$

Comment: Where did you get this problem from? What is the context? Are you working with some form of generalized binomial coefficient? Otherwise, unless $\;a\le0\;$, the equality's right hand makes no sense.

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_and_connection_to_the_binomial_series

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Negative binomial coefficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1619651/negative-binomial-coefficient). See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522045/how-do-i-prove-the-negative-binomial-identity).

Comment: It is used for the general expansion of $(1+x)^\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

A generalized binomial coefficient $\binom{x}{m}$ with $m\in\mathbb N$ but $x$ not necessarily a natural number is given by
$$\frac{x(x-1)\cdots (x-m+1)}{m!}$$
Can you use this to prove it?